# GetAsyncKeyState constantly active

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make an autoclicker to mess around with getkeystate and key pressing functions in VS and c++, for some odd reason it will never stop clicking once it is initially clicked. I looked over my code and couldn't find anything wrong with it, i know the issue is gonna be something stupidly small. Heres my code:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


bool click = false;
int x = 0, y = 0, cps;

void gui()
{
    cout << "Enter desired clicks per second: ";
    cin  >> cps;
}

void clicked()
{

    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) // Left mbutton
        {
            click = true;
        }

        else
        {
            click = false;
        }

        if (click == true)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1000 / cps);
        }
        if (click == false)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    gui();
    clicked();
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe missed to read the documentation about return value of **GetAsyncKeyState**.

The return value of **GetAsyncKeyState** is zero for the following cases:

1. The current desktop is not the active desktop
2. The foreground thread belongs to another process and the desktop does not allow the hook or the journal record.

And,if the **most significant bit** is **set** , the key is **down**.

So, for checking **up**, you need to check, if the **most significant bit** is **reset**.

[Sorry, I am writing the answer on mobile. So, could not provide source code.]

Comment: How would I go about checking if the most significant bit is reset?

Comment: Test if the return value is negative